# Reverse strings

Tags: c, string

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    char *s[]={"To err is human...","But to really mess things up...","One needs to know C!!"};
    int i,j,len,t;
    for(i=0;i<=2;i++)
    {
        len=strlen(s[i]);
        for(j=0;j<len/2;j++)
        {
            t=*(s[i]+len-1-j);
            *(s[i]+len-1-j)=*(s[i]+j);
            *(s[i]+j)=t;
        }
    }
    for(i=0;i<=2;i++)
        printf("%s\n",s[i]);
    return 0;
}
```

What is the error in the above program. I'm just exchanging values from both ends of each string.

Comment: Do you have a problem?

Comment: s is an array of read-only strings.  Try `char s[][100]`

Comment: `char *s[]={(char[]){"To err is human..."},(char[]){"But to really mess things up..."},(char[]){"One needs to know C!!"}};`

Comment: Why??@WilliamPursell

Comment: @NamanSharma See the C FAQ: http://c-faq.com/decl/strlitinit.html You should read the entire FAQ at least once. It is very useful to know what's in there.

Answer (score 2):

Among other things,

`char *s[]={"To err is human...","But to really mess things up...","One needs to know C!!"};`

Here you declare and initialise an array of pointers to char. This way each pointer is pointed to a given string literal. So whatever you do inside your `for` loop to reverse or change those strings would lead to undefined behaviour (in this case the UB is normally a segfault/crash).

At least change this to `char s[][100] = {"To err is human...","But to really mess things up...","One needs to know C!!"};`

Comment: " So whatever you do inside your for loop to reverse or change those strings" --> undefined behavior.  Seg fault is a common possibility,

Answer (score 1):

Well one of the errors is that you don't include `string.h` so this is not compiling. The other one is that your array of `char*`'s will possibly go to a read only memory area and modifying it will cause strange behaviours, so you'd better be using:

```
char s[][255]={"To err is human...",
      "But to really mess things up...","One needs to know C!!"};
```

Answer (score 0):

As the related C FAQ [points out](http://c-faq.com/decl/strlitinit.html):

> Q: What is the difference between these initializations?
>
> ```
> char a[] = "string literal";
> char *p  = "string literal";
> ```
>
> My program crashes if I try to assign a new value to p[i].
>
> A: A string literal (the formal term for a double-quoted string in C source) can be used in two slightly different ways:
>
> 1. As the initializer for an array of char, as in the declaration of `char a[]`, it specifies the initial values of the characters in that array (and, if necessary, its size).
> 2. Anywhere else, it turns into an unnamed, static array of characters, and this unnamed array may be stored in read-only memory, and which therefore cannot necessarily be modified. In an expression context, the array is converted at once to a pointer, as usual (see section 6), so the second declaration initializes p to point to the unnamed array's first element.
>
> Some compilers have a switch controlling whether string literals are writable or not (for compiling old code), and some may have options to cause string literals to be formally treated as arrays of `const char` (for better error catching).

There are many ways of dealing with this. One possibility is using [`strdup`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/strdup.html) in your `reverse_string` function, and reverse that. That requires the caller to take the responsibility of [`free`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/free.html)ing the reversed string.

`strdup` is not a great function, because it needs to find the length of the string that is being duplicated which means you end up traversing one extra time. One way to deal with this is to allocate the memory yourself.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

char *
reverse_string(const char *s) {
    char *cursor;
    char *reversed;
    size_t length;

    if (!s) {
        return NULL;
    }

    length = strlen(s);

    reversed = malloc( length + 1 );

    if (!reversed) {
        return NULL;
    }

    if ( !length ) {
        *reversed = '\0';
        return reversed;
    }

    cursor = reversed;

    while (length--) {
        *(cursor++) = *(s + length);
    }

    *cursor = '\0';

    return reversed;
}


int main(void)
{
    int i;
    char *s[] = {
        "To err is human...",
        "But to really mess things up...",
        "One needs to know C!!"
    };

    for (i = 0; i < sizeof(s)/sizeof(s[0]); ++i) {
        char *reversed = reverse_string( s[i] );
        puts( reversed );
        free( reversed );
    }

    return 0;
}
```